# Eclipse C++ : "Program "g++" not found in PATH"

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, g++

I have gpp installed in my Windows 7 (32 bit) as shown in the picture.

[image]

PATH variable gas g++

```
"%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin\g++"
```

Still eclipse shows the error:

> "Program "g++" not found in PATH".

How can this be resolved?

[image]

Comment: maybe can help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20024817/eclipse-cant-find-mingw-why/20025165#20025165

Answer (score 26):

Today I have bumped into this problem and solved it in the following way. I pressed "Reset defaults" button everywhere I could find it in Eclipse settings (for example, Preferences/C++/Build/Settings/Discovery). After that the error disappeared and the code compiled successfully.

Comment: This helped me too. All was set up correctly, just the message was still showing. *Reset Defaults* in Preferences/C++/Build/Settings cleared the error for good.

Comment: Dont know why but this works for me when compiling GLUS with fresh install of mingw and eclipse c++

Answer (score 17):

This is how I got rid of it:

1. Install the MinGW.
2. Select all files in the Basic Setup and select apply the changes.
3. Select new C++ Project You will be able to see "MinGW GCC" in the toolchain section select the same and create project.

Comment: don't forget to add "C:\MinGW\bin" to your Windows Path variable!

Comment: Note that if you have Eclipse open when installing MinGW or Cygwin, they won't show up as options until you've restarted Eclipse.

Answer (score 11):

You need a `gcc`, `g++` compiler toolchain (on your windows machine) for the eclipse which you have manually downloaded,
One of the options can be done implicit via `cygwin` installation(by selecting proper development packages for `gcc`, `g++`) and then add the location of the compiled `gcc` ,`g++` package like `C:\cygwin\etc\alternatives` to the `PATH` variable for windows environment.

After this open eclipse and go to `Project->properties->C/C++ Tool Chain Editor` and add replace default `GNU C++ compiler` and `GNU C Compiler` with `Cygwin C++ compiler` and `Cygwin C compiler` and rebuild the project. The errors related to `gcc, g++ PATH not found` will now be gone.

Answer (score 11):

I got the same problem with mingw-64 (x86_64-4.9.1-release-posix-seh-rt_v3-rev1), Eclipse Luna 4.4.1 and CDT 8.5.0.201409172108, using Windows 7.

I solved this problem by putting the following two environment variables under

> Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build-> Environment

- name: MINGW_HOME value: (mingw installation directory without "\bin")
- name: MSYS_HOME value: (msys installation directory without "\bin")

You can check

> Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Discovery -> CDT GCC
>   Built-in Compiler Settings MinGW [ Shared ]

, if it doesn't complain "Toolchain MinGW GCC is not detected on this system" then you're all set.

Comment: This has worked for me! Thanks a lot! MINGW_HOME =C:\msys64\mingw64, MSYS_HOME =C:\msys64

Answer (score 10):

You need:

```
C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin
```

in the `PATH`.

and not

```
C:\cygnus\cygwin-b20\H-i586-cygwin32\bin\g++
```

as you wrote.

Comment: The same error exist even when I changed the path as suggested.

Comment: Did you restart your `cmd.exe` after changing the `PATH`. Did you check you have the new path with `echo %PATH%`?

Comment: I have reatrted the system - hope that will restart cmd.exe also. How to set the path with echo?  The environment variable name is "Path" not "PATH". Is that a problem?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, the only solution that worked for me was this:

1. Open command-line and check whether "g++" actually executes the compiler
2. If (1) works, uncheck Project->Build automatically in Eclipse
3. Clean project
4. Build project

Comment: This worked! Nothing else here worked. Everything was setup correctly, but I had to uncheck `Build automatically`. Blah!

Answer (score 7):

The `PATH` is locate at Project Properties > C/C++ Build > Environment (see screenshot below).

[image]

For your reference, I am using MinGW, I got the same error before I got the MSYS install. Later I found out that I also need MSYS to be install because the `make.exe` wasn't come with MinGW. (I don't this error was cause be MSYS.)

After MSYS is installed, add MSYS and MinGW path into environment variable, restart Eclipse. Remember to rebuild your project in order to rectify the error. If error still persist after restart, recreate the workspace. At least this has solved the problem on my site, hopes this help on you too.

Good luck!

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem: Eclipse couldn't find (g++) and (gcc) in PATH even they were accessible from command-line. I was also sure they are pointed by PATH correctly.

I have just deleted the (.metadata) folder from Eclipse's Workspace as a mean to reset it and this worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem. The error is raised, but the code is compiled and linked. The error was caused by the Error Parser using a different configuration than the one that is compiled.

The error parser configuration was only valid for the Linux configuration of my software. My active configuration was set for MinGW and Windows.

Solution:

- In Elipse under **Windows->Preferences->C/C++->Indexer** set Build Configuration for the indexer to **Use active build configuration**.
- Clean and rebuild, otherwise the old errors will remain visible

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it has nothing to do here, but it could be useful for someone.
I installed jdk on: `D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin`
So I added it to `%PATH%` variable and checked it on cmd and everything was ok, but Eclipse kept showing me that error.
I used quotation marks on `%PATH%` so it reads something like:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32;"D:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_06\bin"
```

and problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem and I solved it by:

Installing g++ The GNU C++ compiler using Ubuntu Software Center

Changing in: Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Settings -> Discovery -> CDT GCC Build in Complier Settings [Shared]
from: ${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"
to: /usr/bin/${COMMAND} -E -P -v -dD "${INPUTS}"

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Sublime..

1. Right click on my computer
2. Advanced system settings
3. Environment variables
4. in system variables, change path to location of '...\MinGW\bin'

Example: D:\work\sublime\MinGW\bin

Answer (score 2):

For me it got fixed with:

Go to:
Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Environment

Then press "Add..."

Name: `MINGW_HOME`

Value: `C:\MinGW` (yours might be different if you choose a custom path)

Hit "Apply and Close"

Now, it shoud work if you did everything correctly

Answer (score 1):

i think cgywin might not work for you as you can only compile your code in Win7 if you fire up the command prompt; you need to use MinGW compiler toolset instead. After you have install your compiler, go to Properties->C/C++ Build->Tool Chain Editor -> Change your current toolchain to MinGW GCC.

Answer (score 1):

All the tips did not work for me using the Gaisler Tools for GR712RC Installation for OS RTEMS.
I'm using the Eclipse Kepler.

The simple way was making a **copy** of `sparc-rtems-gcc.exe` to `gcc.exe`, and `sparc-rtems-g++.exe` to `g++.exe`, in the `C:\opt\rtems-4.10-mingw\bin` directory.

Answer (score 1):

WINDOWS 7

If there is anyone new reading this, make sure to simply try a clean install of mingw before any of this. It will save you sooooo much time if that is your problem.

I opened up wingw installer, selected every program for removal, apply changes (under installation tab, upper left corner), closed out, went back in and installed every file (in "Basic Setup" section) availible. after that eclipse worked fine using "MinGW GCC" toolchain when starting a new C++ project.

I hope this works for someone else.
If not, I would do a reinstall of JDK (Java Developer's Kit) and ECLIPSE as well. I have a 64bit system but I could only get the 32bit versions of Eclipse and JDK to work together.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I didnt *mark for instalation* the *mingw32-gcc-g++* *package* in the *installation manager*, that's why eclipse didn't know it.

Needed to go to the instalation manager, mark it (in *basic setup* tab) and *update catalogue*

Comment: Thanks. Assuming this installation manager is in Eclipse, where can I find it? No match found in Help Search. This is V4.7.2.

Answer (score 1):

First Install MinGW or other C/C++ compiler as it's required by Eclipse C++.

Use https://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw-w64/
as unbelievably the download.cnet.com's version has malware attached.

Back to Eclipse.

Now in all those path settings that the Eclipse Help manual talks about INSTEAD of typing the path, **Select Variables** and

```
**MINGW_HOME**
```

and do so for all instances which would ask for the compiler's path.

First would be to click **Preferences** of the whatever project and **C/C++ General** then **Paths and Symbols** and add the

```
**MINGW_HOME** to those paths of for the compiler.
```

Next simply add the home directory to the **Build Variables** under the **C++/C Build**

[Build Variables Screen Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Jygx.png)

Answer (score 1):

If you have your PATH setup and you can see g++ --version via the command line, then try to delete the project and create a new c++ project.

So the reset defaults might work but I think it has to update the PATH if it wasn't added before.

Answer (score 1):

Had this problem on windows 10, eclipse Neon Release (4.6.0) and MSYS2 installed.
Eclipse kept complaining that "Program 'g++' not found in PATH” and "Program 'gcc' not found in PATH”, yet it was compiling and running my C++ code.
From the command prompt, I could run g++.

Solution was to define the C++ Environmental variable for eclipse called 'PATH' to point to windows variable called 'path' also $(Path).
Menus: Preferences>>C/C++>>Build>>Environment

Looks like eclipse is case sensitive with the name of this environmental, while windows doesn't care about the case.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is that eclipse cannot find your gcc or g++ environment variable path.

You might have tried to run `c` or `c++` or `fortran` but `eclipse` cannot find out the compiler.

So, add the path in your environment variable.

1. Windows -> Search -environment variables -> click on environmental variables at bottom.
2. Click on path ->edit -> new -> your variable path

Path should be entire, for example:

```
C:\Users\mahidhai\cygwin64\usr\sbin
```

Make sure that the variable is permanently stored. It is not erased after you close the environment variables GUI.

Sometimes you might find it difficult to add a path variable.
Make sure windows is updated.

Even if Windows is updated and you have problems, directly go to the registry and navigate to the below.

```
HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

Add your path here. Remove any unnecessary repetitions of path variables.

**Note:**
You need to add your path variables in system environment variables -path

Answer (score 1):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLIX0.jpg)If you just want to run C program but meet this error, it might mean that MinGw c++ compiler has not been installed even if "C:\MinGW\bin" has already been added to Windows Path variable.

**Solution:**

1. Run "mingw-get-setup.exe" to open MinGW Installation Manager
2. Open All Packages->MinGw->MinGW Base System->MinGW Compiler Suite
3. Select the following compilers to install:

   . mingw32-gcc-g++

   . mingw32-gcc-v3-core

   . mingw32-gcc-vc-g++
4. Click Installation->Apply Changes to apply the above changes
5. Wait for the installation finishing(There might be some errors, just ignore them).
6. Restart Eclipse.
7. Done.

It Worked in my environment.

Hope it works in your case.