# Configuring Eclipse Juno for C++

Tags: c++

I have a 64-bit windows laptop with Eclipse Juno and I'm having trouble getting C++ to work on it.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


int main()
{
cout << "hello World!" << endl;
return 0;
}
```

The error I receive is "Launch failed. Binary not found"

I've tried what other people have said to do in the preferences but I don't have the same ones so I'm a little stuck. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you installed CDT?

Answer (score 1):

To get C++ to work on eclipse, you first need to install the [CDT plugin](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/). I assume the lack of options means that it is not installed. You can follow the instructions from the link to install it, and try again.

Alternatively, you can download [Eclipse for C/C++ developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) which should come preinstalled with it.

Comment: +1 (and I prefer plan-B on fresh installs. Much less headache.)

Comment: @WhozCraig I agree, and so does google. They have their own bundle for android + native

Comment: I have the same problem after having installed Eclipse for c/C== developers on a Windows 64-bit machine. Eclipse Juno for C/C++ comes with CDT package pre-installed. During build I see `g++, gcc, and make programs not found` in the problems description.

Comment: @Gevorg, can you look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703432/eclipse-c-program-g-not-found-in-path ? If your cygwin is installed, you might be having trouble with your `PATH` which is what that question discusses