# Program "g++" not found in PATH

Tags: android, c++, windows, eclipse, opencv

i have problem when add openCV native C, to my project. first it just say

"Program "g++" not found in PATH"
"Program "gcc" not found in PATH"

but when I right click on my project --> Android Tools --> Add Native, I got more error, this is the error:

[image: error]

and this is what the console say:
[image: console]

I have no idea what should I do? someone can help me?

And This the program that I use:
- OS Windows 7
- Eclipse Juno
- OpenCV 2.4.5

Comment: Have you tried with resetting to the default settings in eclipse?

Comment: did you mean like in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703432/eclipse-c-program-g-not-found-in-path , I have been do that, but it didn't solve the problem

Answer (score -1):

If your IDE is eclipse,you must reset to the default settings. You can do it as following:

1- open Eclipse->**Windows->Preferences->C/C++->Build->Settings**

2- You will find, under the '**Discovery**' tab, two options: [**reset**] or [**restore defaults**] the 'CDT GCC Build in Complier Settings [Shared]' or all settings.