# Eclipse can't find MinGW. Why?

Tags: eclipse, mingw

I installed both correctly, but it doesn't matter if I set up the path to compiler correctly or not because it can't find gcc and g++. I checked it with explorer, they were at the correct location. I tried everything I could, even I ran Eclipse in backwards compatibility mode and as an administrator.

EDIT: I'll using Visual Studio 2012 for a while if Eclipse can't be at least as user friendly to having find a solution to the problem under one hour via web.

Answer (score 2):

Download [this](http://garr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/mingw/Installer/mingw-get-setup.exe)  , chose the desired compilers (gcc and g++) . Make sure you have the value `C:\mingw64` in `PATH` variable under `environment variables` .

Answer (score 1):

I had to reload my workspace in order to get Eclipse to recognize that.

Also, I had updated the Path variable.

Please follow the same in your case.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't make the Eclipse (LUNA) to find MinGW on my computer (there were no MinGW available in **Preferences>C/C++/New C/C++ Project Wizard**) even after I have specified PATH as "C:\MinGW\bin" in **Preferences>C/C++/Build>Environment**, so what I did afterwards was:

1. Create a simple "Hello world" C project without specifying any toolchains
2. (at this step I tried to Build All, and it failed)
3. Go to **Project>Properties**, suprisingly, here I could see MinGW GCC as an available choice for Current toolchain. Select it.
4. Now I could build and run the project

Hopefully, it helps!