# g++ and gcc is not found in path in omnet++

Tags: omnet++

I am new in omnet++ and found some difficulty. My code is ok but the problem is **g++ and gcc is not found in PATH**. I have no idea why this problem is going on. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Answer (score 5):

Start `mingwenv.cmd` from main OMNeT++ directory, type `omnetpp` and don't close console. All needed paths will be correctly set (path to `gcc` and `g++` too).

Answer (score 3):

Since I do not have enough reps to comment, I will reply here.

First (obvious) things first, are you sure that gcc/g++ compiler suite are installed on your machine? If they are not installed, then the IDE can not find them.
Try installing them, and restart the IDE.

Also, if you have played around with the preferences of the IDE, make sure to restart things to defaults as suggested here: [Eclipse C++ : "Program "g++" not found in PATH"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703432/eclipse-c-program-g-not-found-in-path)