# omnet++ errors, program "g++" not found in PATH, program "gcc" not found in PATH

Tags: gcc, g++, omnet++

Actually I fixed this by starting omnetpp from mingwenv.cmd from main directory. (see [g++ and gcc is not found in path in omnet++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878462/g-and-gcc-is-not-found-in-path-in-omnet)).

Today, I did the same, but got the errors again. Any help?

See the screen shot...
[image]

Comment: What do you see in mingwenv console when you type `g++`? It should be something like: `g++.exe: fatal error: no input files`. If it is something else: type `echo $PATH` in mingw console and show the result as well as write in which directory you have `OMNeT++`.

Comment: You might have moved OMNeT++ after last building it. If so, you could try rebuilding OMNeT++ (by running configure and make again).