# Installation error in Omnet++ in Windows 10, C compiler not found

Tags: omnet++

I am trying to install Omnet-5.6.2 in my windows 10 64 bit.

When I enter `./configure` in **mingwenv,cmd** file I got in error:-

```
configure: loading site script /mingw64/etc/config.site
checking build system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
checking host system type... x86_64-w64-mingw32
configure: -----------------------------------------------
configure: reading configure.user for your custom settings
configure: -----------------------------------------------
checking for clang... no
checking for icc... no
checking for gcc... no
checking for clang... no
checking for cc... no
checking for xlc... no
configure: error: in `/f/Omnet/omnetpp-5.6.2':
configure: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details
```

I already have GCC compiler in MinGW and it's path-variable is set.

GCC version : `gcc (MinGW.org GCC Build-2) 9.2.0`

My config.log file:-

```
This file contains any messages produced by compilers while
running configure, to aid debugging if configure makes a mistake.

It was created by configure, which was
generated by GNU Autoconf 2.69.  Invocation command line was

  $ ./configure 

## --------- ##
## Platform. ##
## --------- ##

hostname = DESKTOP-9J5H09N
uname -m = x86_64
uname -r = 2.10.0(0.325/5/3)
uname -s = MINGW64_NT-10.0
uname -v = 2018-02-09 15:25

/usr/bin/uname -p = unknown
/bin/uname -X     = unknown

/bin/arch              = x86_64
/usr/bin/arch -k       = unknown
/usr/convex/getsysinfo = unknown
/usr/bin/hostinfo      = unknown
/bin/machine           = unknown
/usr/bin/oslevel       = unknown
/bin/universe          = unknown

PATH: .
PATH: /f/Omnet/omnetpp-5.6.2//bin
PATH: /mingw64/bin
PATH: /usr/local/bin
PATH: /usr/bin
PATH: /bin
PATH: /c/Windows/System32
PATH: /c/Windows
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/Wbem
PATH: /c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/
PATH: /usr/bin/site_perl
PATH: /usr/bin/vendor_perl
PATH: /usr/bin/core_perl


## ----------- ##
## Core tests. ##
## ----------- ##

configure:1970: loading site script /mingw64/etc/config.site
| # This file is in public domain.
| # Original author: Karlson2k (Evgeny Grin)
| # Written for MSys2/MinGW64 to help running 'configure' scripts
| 
| # Defaults for MinGW64-targeted programs
| 
| # Set proper selfname on bash and fallback to default name on other shells
| test -n "${BASH_SOURCE}" 2>/dev/null && config_site_me="${BASH_SOURCE[0]##*/}" || config_site_me=config.site
| 
| # Set default 'host' to speedup configure
| if test -z "$build_alias"; then
|   build_alias="${MSYSTEM_CHOST-x86_64-w64-mingw32}" && \
|     $as_echo "$config_site_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: default build_alias set to $build_alias" >&5 
| fi
| 
| # Set default 'prefix' to "/mingw64"
| if ( test -z "$prefix" || test "x$prefix" = "xNONE" ) && \
|    ( test -z "$exec_prefix" || test "x$exec_prefix" = "xNONE" ); then
|   prefix="${MSYSTEM_PREFIX-/mingw64}" && \
|     $as_echo "$config_site_me:${as_lineno-$LINENO}: default prefix set to $prefix" >&5
| fi
config.site:13: default build_alias set to x86_64-w64-mingw32
config.site:20: default prefix set to /mingw64
configure:2106: checking build system type
configure:2120: result: x86_64-w64-mingw32
configure:2140: checking host system type
configure:2153: result: x86_64-w64-mingw32
configure:2202: -----------------------------------------------
configure:2204: reading configure.user for your custom settings
configure:2206: -----------------------------------------------
configure:2345: checking for clang
configure:2375: result: no
configure:2345: checking for icc
configure:2375: result: no
configure:2345: checking for gcc
configure:2375: result: no
configure:2345: checking for clang
configure:2375: result: no
configure:2345: checking for cc
configure:2375: result: no
configure:2345: checking for xlc
configure:2375: result: no
configure:2397: error: in `/f/Omnet/omnetpp-5.6.2':
configure:2399: error: no acceptable C compiler found in $PATH
See `config.log' for more details

## ---------------- ##
## Cache variables. ##
## ---------------- ##

ac_cv_build=x86_64-w64-mingw32
ac_cv_env_CCC_set=
ac_cv_env_CCC_value=
ac_cv_env_CC_set=
ac_cv_env_CC_value=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CPPFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXCPP_value=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_CXXFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_CXX_set=
ac_cv_env_CXX_value=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_LDFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_set=
ac_cv_env_LIBS_value=
ac_cv_env_PERL_set=
ac_cv_env_PERL_value=
ac_cv_env_SWIG_set=
ac_cv_env_SWIG_value=
ac_cv_env_XMKMF_set=
ac_cv_env_XMKMF_value=
ac_cv_env_YACC_set=
ac_cv_env_YACC_value=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_set=
ac_cv_env_YFLAGS_value=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_build_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_host_alias_value=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_set=
ac_cv_env_target_alias_value=
ac_cv_host=x86_64-w64-mingw32

## ----------------- ##
## Output variables. ##
## ----------------- ##

AKAROA_CFLAGS=''
AKAROA_LIBS=''
AR=''
ARFLAG_OUT=''
AS=''
AS_NEEDED_OFF=''
AS_NEEDED_ON=''
A_LIB_SUFFIX='.a'
CC=''
CFLAGS=''
CFLAGS_DEBUG=' -g -Wall'
CFLAGS_RELEASE=' -O3 -DNDEBUG=1'
CPPFLAGS=''
CXX=''
CXXCPP=''
CXXFLAGS=' -std=c++11'
DEFINES=''
DEFS=''
DLLTOOL=''
DLL_LIB_SUFFIX='.dll'
ECHO_C=''
ECHO_N='-n'
ECHO_T=''
EMBED_TCL_CODE='yes'
EXEEXT=''
EXE_SUFFIX=''
HAVE_DLOPEN=''
JAVA_CFLAGS=''
JAVA_LIBS=''
JNILIBS_IF_POSSIBLE=''
JNI_LIB_SUFFIX='$(SO_LIB_SUFFIX)'
JRE=''
LDFLAGS=''
LDFLAG_IMPLIB='-Wl,--out-implib,'
LDFLAG_INCLUDE='-Wl,-u,'
LDFLAG_LIB='-l'
LDFLAG_LIBPATH='-L'
LEX=''
LEXLIB=''
LEX_OUTPUT_ROOT=''
LIBOBJS=''
LIBS=''
LIB_PREFIX='lib'
LN='ln -f'
LTLIBOBJS=''
MAKE=''
MAKEDEPEND='opp_makedep -Y --objdirtree'
MKPATH='mkdir -p'
MOC=''
MPICPP=''
MPICXX=''
MPI_CFLAGS=''
MPI_LIBS=''
MSGC='opp_msgc'
NEDTOOL='opp_nedtool'
OBJEXT=''
OMNETPP_BUILDID='200518-aa79d0918f'
OMNETPP_EDITION='Academic Public License -- NOT FOR COMMERCIAL USE'
OMNETPP_PRODUCT='OMNeT++'
OMNETPP_RELEASE='omnetpp-5.6.2'
OMNETPP_VERSION='5.6.2'
OSGEARTH_CFLAGS=''
OSGEARTH_LIBS=''
OSG_CFLAGS=''
OSG_LIBS=''
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT=''
PACKAGE_NAME=''
PACKAGE_STRING=''
PACKAGE_TARNAME=''
PACKAGE_URL=''
PACKAGE_VERSION=''
PATH_SEPARATOR=':'
PERL=''
PIC_FLAGS=''
PLATFORM=''
PREFER_SQLITE_RESULT_FILES='no'
PRIVATE_JRE=''
PTHREAD_CFLAGS=''
PTHREAD_LIBS=''
QMAKE=''
QTENV_LDFLAGS=''
QT_CFLAGS=''
QT_LIBS=''
RANLIB=''
RCC=''
SHARED_LIBS='yes'
SHARED_LIB_SUFFIX='$(SO_LIB_SUFFIX)'
SHELL='/bin/sh'
SHLIB_LD=''
SHLIB_POSTPROCESS='opp_shlib_postprocess'
SMC='opp_smc'
SO_LIB_SUFFIX='.so'
STRIP=''
SWIG=''
SYS_LIBS=''
TK_CFLAGS=''
TK_LIBS=''
TOOLCHAIN_NAME=''
UIC=''
WHOLE_ARCHIVE_OFF=''
WHOLE_ARCHIVE_ON=''
WISH=''
WITH_NETBUILDER='yes'
WITH_OSG='yes'
WITH_OSGEARTH='yes'
WITH_PARSIM='yes'
WITH_QTENV='yes'
WITH_SYSTEMC='no'
WITH_TKENV='no'
XMKMF=''
XMLPARSER=''
XML_CFLAGS=''
XML_LIBS=''
YACC=''
YFLAGS=''
ZLIB_CFLAGS=''
ZLIB_LIBS=''
ac_ct_CC=''
ac_ct_CXX=''
bindir='${exec_prefix}/bin'
build='x86_64-w64-mingw32'
build_alias='x86_64-w64-mingw32'
build_cpu='x86_64'
build_os='mingw32'
build_vendor='w64'
datadir='${datarootdir}'
datarootdir='${prefix}/share'
docdir='${datarootdir}/doc/${PACKAGE}'
dvidir='${docdir}'
exec_prefix='NONE'
host='x86_64-w64-mingw32'
host_alias=''
host_cpu='x86_64'
host_os='mingw32'
host_vendor='w64'
htmldir='${docdir}'
includedir='${prefix}/include'
infodir='${datarootdir}/info'
libdir='${exec_prefix}/lib'
libexecdir='${exec_prefix}/libexec'
localedir='${datarootdir}/locale'
localstatedir='${prefix}/var'
mandir='${datarootdir}/man'
oldincludedir='/usr/include'
pdfdir='${docdir}'
prefix='/mingw64'
program_transform_name='s,x,x,'
psdir='${docdir}'
runstatedir='${localstatedir}/run'
sbindir='${exec_prefix}/sbin'
sharedstatedir='${prefix}/com'
sysconfdir='${prefix}/etc'
target_alias=''
tmp_CXX=''

## ----------- ##
## confdefs.h. ##
## ----------- ##

/* confdefs.h */
#define PACKAGE_NAME ""
#define PACKAGE_TARNAME ""
#define PACKAGE_VERSION ""
#define PACKAGE_STRING ""
#define PACKAGE_BUGREPORT ""
#define PACKAGE_URL ""

configure: exit 1
```

Comment: Did you use the [installation guide](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/InstallGuide.pdf)? Can you type `omnetpp` in the console? So all needed paths are set. I found it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29878462/g-and-gcc-is-not-found-in-path-in-omnet).

Comment: I can only use omentpp command after running ./configure and make . Nut in my case error is coming in ./configure command.

Comment: Are you able to call `gcc` or `clang` from MinGW console? If not, try to extract OMNeT++ package using 7zip. Additionally, turn off antivirus real-time protection.

Comment: yes gcc is working , but I have not installed clang.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution to this.

You can set path of your GCC or any other **C** compiler by writing following command in **mingwenv.cmd**:-

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/c/MinGW/bin
```

After that run `./configure` and it will work fine.

If after using above method you are getting `Qtenv cannot find qmake...` error then you have to extract Omnet bundle again and this time disable your antivirus and ransomware protection.

After this run your **mingwenv.cmd** and follow the installation steps.

Answer (score 1):

Before installing make sure to disable antivirus. Some files of **.7z**  missed due to ransomware protection.