# Eclipse neon C program not getting build g++ and gcc not found in path error

Tags: c, eclipse, gcc, eclipse-luna, eclipse-neon

Today I have installed for c  and c++ development in windows 7 64 bit os. when creating the  project getting error in console .

Eclipse neon version :
Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
Version: Neon.2 Release (4.6.2)
Build id: 20161208-0600

When opening eclipse  getting below error in the IDE
1) "g++" not found in PATH
2) gcc not found in Path.

I have installed MinGW GCC compiler still getting error in Eclipse neon and Luna.

More attached a video screencast.

http://recordit.co/E1lFakauTK

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eclipse C++ : "Program "g++" not found in PATH"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703432/eclipse-c-program-g-not-found-in-path)

Answer (score 0):

After many hours looking for the problem I solved it by adding a variable:

1. Open Window-->Preferences-->C/C++-->Build-->Environment
2. Click on Add
3. Write in Variable: PATH
4. Write in Value: C:{your MinGW Directory}\bin

Hope it helps.